# Filtering property of Realm Object

Tags: ios, json, swift, filter, realm

Is it possible to filter empty values with predicate? For example, I have a Realm object that looks like this:

```
class CropData: Object  {

@objc dynamic var cropper = ""
@objc dynamic var x: CGFloat = 0.0
@objc dynamic var y: CGFloat = 0.0
@objc dynamic var width : CGFloat = 0.0
@objc dynamic var height: CGFloat = 0.0
@objc dynamic var scaleX: CGFloat = 0.0
@objc dynamic var scaleY: CGFloat = 0.0
@objc dynamic var rotate: CGFloat = 0.0


override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
return "cropper"
}
```

Sample json data

```
{"cropper": "","x": "0","y": "0","width": "0","height": "0","scaleX": "0","scaleY": "0","rotate": "0"}
```

In this example, is there a way I can filter or ignore the empty "cropper" property?

Comment: What do you want to filter: json or array of CropData?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter like this

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let result = realm.objects(CropData).filter("cropper = %@", <#YOUR VALUE#>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Predicate` to filter it

get all object with cropper = "" :

```
let result = realm.objects(CropData.self).filter("cropper = %@", "")
```

or ignore it

```
let result = realm.objects(CropData.self).filter("cropper != %@", "")
```

You can read more `Predicate` syntax here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html